# Convert to string untagged child Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap some html document using BeautifulSoup4 but I'm stuck trying to scrap this div:

```
<div class="small-info" style="margin-top: 4px;">
                5
                 <sup>th</sup>  
                August 2018
</div>
```

I'm trying to get "5 th August 2018", how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `get_text()` and remove extra spaces

```
html="<div class='small-info' style='margin-top: 4px;''>5<sup>th</sup>August 2018</div>"
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
div=soup.find("div",{"class","small-info"})
text=div.get_text().replace("  ","")

#text : 5 th August 2018
```

Comment: It worked , but how get_text().replace(" ","") works? I dont get it. How that skips the sup tag

Comment: get_text() returns the string in the div. replace is to just remove extra white spaces and replace it with nothing